# Generate and Send .ics file via Symfony2 (Swift Mailer)

Tags: php, symfony, icalendar, swiftmailer

I am trying to generate a calendar event MS Outlook/Google Calendar in Symfony2, while the email is sent with .ics file but I am not able to get the event added to calendar. When I try to open the file it says

```
Failed to import events: Unable to process your iCal/CSV file..
```

This is how I am trying to generate the iCal file

```
$message="
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    VERSION:2.0
    CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
    METHOD:REQUEST
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTART:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingStartTime))."
    DTEND:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingEndTime))."
    DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingStartTime))."
    ORGANIZER;CN=XYZ:mailto:do-not-reply@example.com
    UID:".rand(5, 1500)."
    ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Sample:emailaddress@testemail.com
    DESCRIPTION:".$this->getUser()->getName()." requested Phone/Video Meeting Request
    LOCATION: Phone/Video
    SEQUENCE:0
    STATUS:CONFIRMED
    SUMMARY:Meeting has been scheduled by ".$this->getUser()->getName()."
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR";

$messageObject = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
$messageObject->setContentType("text/calendar");
$messageObject->setSubject("Your meeting has been booked")
              ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user'), "From Name")
              ->setTo($this->getUser()->getEmail())
              ->setBody(trim($message));
$this->get('mailer')->send($messageObject);
```

I will really appreciate if I can get some help on what I am doing wrong which leads to the error of **Failed to import events: Unable to process your iCal/CSV file**

Comment: Why don't you write the ics file on your server then send it as attachment?

Comment: @Veve can you show me an example on this? as it would really help a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead write your iCal file on your server (using the [Filesystem component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem/introduction.html) or with native PHP functions like [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)) then send it as attachment:

```
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOExceptionInterface;

$fs = new Filesystem();

//temporary folder, it has to be writable
$tmpFolder = '/tmp/';

//the name of your file to attach
$fileName = 'meeting.ics';

$icsContent = "
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    VERSION:2.0
    CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
    METHOD:REQUEST
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTART:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingStartTime))."
    DTEND:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingEndTime))."
    DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingStartTime))."
    ORGANIZER;CN=XYZ:mailto:do-not-reply@example.com
    UID:".rand(5, 1500)."
    ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Sample:emailaddress@testemail.com
    DESCRIPTION:".$this->getUser()->getName()." requested Phone/Video Meeting Request
    LOCATION: Phone/Video
    SEQUENCE:0
    STATUS:CONFIRMED
    SUMMARY:Meeting has been scheduled by ".$this->getUser()->getName()."
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR"
;

//creation of the file on the server
$icfFile = $fs->dumpFile($tmpFolder.$fileName, $icsContent);

//message to include as body to your mail
$body = 'Hello...';

$messageObject = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
$messageObject->setSubject("Your meeting has been booked")
              ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user'), "From Name")
              ->setTo($this->getUser()->getEmail())
              ->setBody($body)
              ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($tmpFolder.$fileName))
;
$this->get('mailer')->send($messageObject);

//remove the created file
$fs->remove(array('file', $tmpFolder, $fileName));
```

Comment: Do anybody know a lib for the OOP Creation of ICS files like this?

Comment: Are you affilated with that package? It seems, it doesnt have composer support. Thanks anyway. Dont want to hijack this thread any further. Sorry for beeing OffTopic.

Comment: @mblaettermann not affiliated at all, just one of the results I've found during a search.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an OOP creation, you can use the package : https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal

Installation can be done using composer and there's no need for adding a bundle in appKernel for SF users.

Comment: Please state affiliation with the package :)